# Phabricator: how to fire herald rule on acceptance of of Audit?

Tags: phabricator

Is there a way to create herald rule to fire once a audit has been marked as accepted? 
Basically what I am trying to do is to trigger build job once a commit has been audited and marked as accepted

cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no herald rule for accepted audits. Like CEPA already said, you need to to a pre commit review. You can create a diff without using the cli `arcanist`.

1. Do your stuff in the repo
2. Stage and commit changes
3. Create a diff for example with: `git diff origin/master > diff`
4. Create a new diff in phabricator with: Differential > Create Diff and paste the file there. If you can't find the URI just use the link *https:///differential/diff/create/*

Now you could create herald rules to react on new diffs and add blocking reviewers for example.

You could also protect commiting to master.

Keep in mind: This isn't the recommended way to work with differentials.

Answer (score 1):

There is no built in functionality for reacting to commit audits. Phabricator has developed a "pre-commit" code review system that would accomplish this by putting the review process before the commit.  Then, once it is reviewed it can then be "landed"/committed and then the build can kick off.

For more information on their pre-commit review, please read their ["Reviews vs. Audit" doc](https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabricator/article/reviews_vs_audit/).

Comment: My understanding is to do this one would need to use Arc tool to have pre commit reviews. Is their a way to do it with just plain old git

Comment: I don't think there is.  We use arc when interacting with Phabricator.